# Перенос базы данных вордпресс сайта на другой хост только с FTP

Tags: база-данных, wordpress, ftp, хостинг

Как перенести базу данных сайта написанного на wordpress?

Есть только данные FTP

Answer (score 1):

Использовать [MySQLDumper](http://www.mysqldumper.net/). Утилита написанная на PHP и Perl, позволяющая перенести данные из My SQL на хостингах, где нет доступа к шелу.